# Replace function in a column where comma is replaced by apostrophe and comma?

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, replace, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table Employees

```
EmpGid    Employees
 1          john
 2          john,kevin
 3          Tom,Peter,harry
 4          Peter,Mike,Frank
```

I need ouput look likes below when i select employees

```
 Employees
   john
   john','kevin
   Tom','Peter','harry
   Peter','Mike','Frank

       I am using Replace but i am unable replace ',' where , is present .

       Can some one help me how to replace.
```

Comment: Store your data properly.

Comment: Care to leave a comment Mr Down Voter??

Comment: I did not down-vote but storing comma delimited values like that is usually a bad design choice and leads to significant problems when you try to interact with/query the data in anything but the most trivial fashion. (A 1-to-many table with multiple EmpGid each with a single EmployeeName would be better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will replace , with ',' :

```
SELECT *, replace(Employees, ',',''',''') FROM Employees
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be like

```
select REPLACE('John,Kevin',',',''',''')
```

Which will result in `John','Kevin`